# Lenovo Thinkpad E15 Gen2 shutting down about 5 minutes after login

Tags: windows-11

Recently my Lenovo Thinkpad E15 Gen2 laptop started shutting down about 5 minutes after login.

There is nothing relevant in Event Viewer or Task Scheduler.

The laptop is not overheating.

The laptop is connected to power and shows 100% battery.

Thoughts appreciated.

**Edit**: The laptop failed some memory tests. What is the prognosis from here?

[image]

Comment: Run the Lenovo Diagnostics App and look for hardware errors - bad memory can do this.   Run Kaspersky TDSS Killer to look for Root Kit Viruses.   Given 5 minutes each time, I lean toward bad memory.

Comment: Use the built in diagnostics tool by pressing F10 on boot to rule out a hardware defect.

Comment: Thanks, @John, updated my question with a failed memory test.

Comment: If the RAM is failing and the RAM is on a SIMM or DIMM (something removable) I would remove them all and then try each one individually and see what the test shows. If you have one good RAM module and one bad RAM module, you need to replace the bad one. Or better yet, buy two new RAM modules.

Comment: Thanks, removing the supplementary RAM resolved the issue.